# Sort duplicates inside array in different sub arrays

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have an array containing duplicates in the following format:

```
arr[]={ 2,9,1,5,1,4,9,7,2,1,4 }
```

I want to sort the array in place such that all the duplicate elements are moved towards the end and sorted in different sub arrays like following:

```
arr[]={ 1,2,4,5,7,9, 1,2,4,9, 1 }
```

There is no range for Integers for the array specified.
Following is the code which i tried. This code recursively sorts the sub-arrays and then move duplicates towards the end. But Complexity wise this is not optimal solution.
Please suggest if it can be solve in `O(n)` or `O(nlogn)`.  Entire code is as follows:

```
public static int sortDuplicates(int a[],int start,int end){           
    int i, k,temp;
    if(start==end)
        return 1;
    Arrays.sort(a, start, end);
    k = start;
    for (i = start+1; i < end; i++) {
        if (a[k] != a[i] && a[k]<a[i]) 
        {
           temp=a[k+1];
            a[k+1] = a[i];
            a[i]=temp;
           k++;
        }
    }       
    return sortDuplicates(a,k+1,a.length);  
}
```

Comment: Is this java? if so, please add a java tag.

Comment: Why is the `7` at the very end and not right after the `5`?

Comment: By what arbitrary means is 7 the last number {1,2,4,5,9,1,2,4,9,1,7} ? Shouldn't 1 be the last number {1,2,4,5,7,9,1,2,4,9,1} ?

Comment: To all editors: please be careful to not introduce more errors than your predecessor fixed...

Comment: Yeah I just duplicated someone's work. OP must have had a work in progress and overwrote. Fixed.

Comment: It cannot be solved in `O(n)`, there is still sorting involved.

Comment: Sorry for mistake in O/P array.Just edited it.Thnx for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

I would approach it as follows:

Put all elements and their counts in a hashmap:

```
int[] arr={ 2,9,1,5,1,4,9,7,2,1,4 };
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
for (int elt : arr) {
    int val = 1;
    if (map.containsKey(elt))
        val = map.get(elt) + 1;
    map.put(elt, val);
}
```

Fetch the batches one by one:

```
List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
while (map.size() > 0) {
    List<Integer> subList = new ArrayList<>();     // for the current segment
    Iterator<Integer> it = map.keySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        int elt = it.next();
        subList.add(elt);
        if (map.get(elt) == 1) { // remove all elements with occurence = 1
            it.remove();       
        } else {                 // reduce occurence by 1
            map.put(elt, map.get(elt)-1);
        }
    }
    Collections.sort(subList);  // sort this segment
    result.addAll(subList);     // append to result
}

for (int i : result) {
    System.out.print(i + " ");
}
```

This prints

```
1 2 4 5 7 9 1 2 4 9 1
```

And if I'm not mistaken, it runs in `O(n log n)`.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be an *in-place* algorithm

Comment: @Bergi ah yeah, I totally missed that requirement. My guess is that an in-place algorithm cannot do better than `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach it as follows.

1. Put all the elements in a balanced binary search tree with their counts.
2. Now traverse the tree in an inorder way and keep putting the elements(with `count > 0`) in the array and decreasing their count by 1.
3. time complexity for creating the tree is `O(nlgn)` and for putting elements from tree is `O(n)` and space complexity is `O(n)`.

Problem is if none of elements is being repeated then we are creating the tree in vain.